# What is a single word for something that takes on shape slowly?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word describing something that takes on shape slowly (such as a silhouette in the night that gets more defined the closer you get to it).

It would be great if the word could be used for the process of getting to know someone better (their character would be taking on shape slowly the more you get to know them).

Comment: _Interminable_.

Comment: Words for slow physical, chemical and biological processes, but that I have trouble putting in the context of "getting to know someone better": _relax_, _settle_, _anneal_, _cure_, _set_, _harden_, _cement_, _ossify_, _petrify_? My favourite in this list is _cement_ (_"Over the years, my opinion of John Doe has cemented"_). All of these, however, convey a definite slowness.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The first option that came to mind for me was [coalesce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coalesce):

1:  to grow together

2a :  to unite into a whole :  fuse

3:  to arise from the combination of distinct elements

Comment: Beautiful word, sadly I can't use it as it is not common enough. Thanks!

Comment: Graveto, How do you figure this is anything but the best word?

Comment: @Yeshe please look up my comment on crystallize to see why I chose crystallize over coalesce. :)

Comment: @Yeshe [Because he didn't do any research](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crystalize%2Ccoalesce%2Ccrystallize&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). He hadn't personally heard of "coalesce" and didn't realize it's not only more common than "crystallize" but ***much*** more common and appropriate in this context. ([The vast majority of uses of "crystallize"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=crystallize) are for the geological process, not anything metaphorical.)

Comment: @lly You are definitely right. I personally prefer crystallize but for reasons that were not mentioned in the question. Therefore I find it reasonable to choose coalesce as the new answer instead. Thank you very much for the effort.

Comment: @Graveto You're quite welcome. It is your question, so you can play favorites. Kind of you not to, though, since this really is a better fit.

Answer (score 36):

**crystallize**

to assume definite or concrete form

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/crystallize

> For years, I wondered who had signed up for all of the slots, and eventually a character started **to crystallize** in my imagination.
>
> (from *Real Thrills And High Art In A Poignant Page-Turner Of A Novel* by
> Susan Cheever)

There may be an even better word for it, only it seems to escape me just now.

Comment: I do not think this is correct; it seems to be lacking the "slowless" aspect. Other answers that I consider better: manifest, evolve, take shape.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Things can crystalize slowly. The only thing off about the word is its clarity: it suggests that at the end of the process, there is a hard, pure outline. That said, between this and *coalesce*, this question seems pretty well answered. Your answers are either not a single word or have nothing to do with taking shape: *manifest* is already clear and *evolve* concerns the change from a former shape, not the assumption of a new one.

Comment: That said, because of its firmness, this word doesn't really work for learning about someone's personality unless they are utterly and implacably set in their ways. Odd @Graveto thought this one was better than *coalesce* or *emerge*.

Comment: @lly I already commented one reason on "coalesce". There were actual several reasons for choosing crystallize over coalesce :
1. Crystallize is more of a common word than coalesce (Bonus points!)
2. Coalesce lacks a visual association that crystallize has 
3. Crystallize works very well in german too - coalesce doesn't (I know I didn't mention it working in german as well, but it sill affected my decision)

Comment: @Graveto [No, *coalesce* is much more common than *crystallize*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crystalize%2Ccoalesce%2Ccrystallize&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), given that they're equally common and [*crystallize* is used for the geological process the vast majority of the time](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=crystallize). *Coalesce* is far more visual than *crystallize*, given that the objects are actually coalescing and not remotely crystalline. It's your question and you can bring in philo-Germanism if you like, but this was the wrong call.

Comment: Also, crystallisation can be abrupt. Prepare a saturated solution of sodium acetate in boiling water and decant the liquid while boiling. Allow to stand and cool to room temperature. You have prepared a supersaturated solution. Pour it from a height into a transparent vessel. It crystallises on impact. You cannot describe a process that occurs in about 0.2seconds as slow. Crystallisation _can_ be slow but that is not a characteristic of crystallisation.

Answer (score 18):

Emerge ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emerge))

> 1. to become manifest: become known new problems emerged
> 2. to rise from or as if from an enveloping fluid :  come out into view a diver emerging from the water
> 3. to rise from an obscure or inferior position or condition someone must emerge as a leader
> 4. to come into being through evolution

Comment: I like emerge, although I think there is a small, yet important difference between manifestation and transition - one sounds a lot faster/instantenous than the other!

Comment: Works as long as the effect is similar to something rising from the depths of water. It works better than crystalize for personalities, yeah.

Answer (score 16):

"resolve", opposite of "dissolve".  "the outlines of his true character resolved only gradually..."

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, mainly because I associate resolving something with a problem existing beforehand. Thanks!

Comment: I'd say this meaning is quite common in scientific contexts, but not so much elsewhere. You can *resolve* things better if your imaging system has more *resolution*.

Comment: @Graveto but also think about optical illusions where you don't see it at first, you have to stare a while before it resolves, but it's not really "there", it's a matter of perception, e.g.http://www.illusions.org/dp/1-91.htm

Comment: or these: http://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/3307500

Answer (score 10):

Materialise (Materialize if you are American). Not really so applicable to a relationship developing but ok for a silhouette resolving...

> "**Materialize:** *to come into perceptible existence; appear; become actual or real; be realized or carried out*

Source - "materialise. Dictionary.com. Dictionary.com Unabridged. Random House, Inc. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/materialise (accessed: April 16, 2017).

Comment: Definition and source of the definition is very much appreciated.

Comment: I like it! Very close to crystallize.

Answer (score 8):

How about **take shape**?

OD:

> [**take
>   shape**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/take_shape):
>   assume a distinct form; develop into something definite or
>   tangible. Example:‘the past few months have seen the state's health
>   insurance legislation begin to take shape’
>
> Synonyms: become clear, become definite, become tangible, crystallize,
>   gel, come together, fall into place.

[**The Free Dictionary**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+shape) lists **takes shape** as an idiom, which is kind of like one word ... if you're willing to stretch it. If not, I'll go with **gel**, which hasn't been mentioned yet.

**Addendum**: More examples from OD in response to @Tonepoet's comment. These examples generally show that **taking shape** occurs over time, gradually, slowly, in the OP's sense. **Taking shape** does not occur immediately or abruptly; it implicitly requires time, as per emphasis added and prevalence of various forms of "begin".

> ‘The party, now in its 12th year, helped residents build a sense of
>   community back when the development was ***just*** taking shape.’
>
> ‘The question that remains, however, is what alternative narrative
>   takes shape where the developmental trajectory of the narrative of
>   self-making leaves off.’
>
> ‘As we closed in on the far shore, a small town ***began*** to take shape.’
>
> ‘Alongside the secular model of marriage, an ecclesiastical model is
>   ***beginning*** to take shape and definition.’
>
> ‘A reversal of that conventional wisdom ***began*** taking shape in the
>   early nineties, following the 1989 Exxon Valdez spill in Alaska's
>   Prince William Sound.’
>
> ‘Elation replaced doubt when the schemes ***began*** to take shape.’
>
> ‘While compositions on their previous effort ***had time to develop*** and
>   take shape, here they are set to impact at once.’
>
> ‘Here's a look at some of the other ***developments taking shape*** around
>   town.’
>
> ‘Globally, ambitious efforts to develop wind power are ***beginning*** to
>   take shape.’
>
> ‘The outlines of another strategy also **began** to take shape.’

Comment: If phrasal verbs count as one word, I would also suggest "come together".

Comment: @user1359 Agreed. Thx.

Comment: Aside from not being a single word, it is also something the O.P. is likely to have already considered and might not have the semantic nuance sought. Do you have any evidence to suggest that "take shape" is implicitly *slow* unless otherwise modified, because I've seen adverbial modifiers of speed, [namely quickly and slowly](http://archive.is/3rnKn), applied to it. Granted, it is nowhere near the same order of magnitude as the phrasal verb itself, but it'd seem pointless to modify it with quickly or slowly in any case unless it was implicitly neutral speed.

Comment: I agree with "take shape" fitting my description - but sadly I was looking for one word and one word only!
Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: @Graveto I get it. No issue here. Hope you got what you want.

Comment: coalesse might be similar

Answer (score 6):

Congeal might also be an option:

> con·geal kənˈjēl/
>
> 2. take shape or coalesce, especially to form a satisfying whole.
>          "the ballet failed to congeal as a single oeuvre"

Comment: Very interesting word, thanks for the addition!
Seems to be very uncommon though - still nice!

Comment: "Over the course of our relationship, her personality began to congeal before me"... isn't wrong but it's certainly unpleasant.

Comment: It was the first word to come to my mind but it strikes me as having an icky connotation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57335/discussion-between-user1359-and-lly).

Answer (score 6):

**Develop** may work for you as well

MWD (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/develop):

> #### transitive verb
>
> 1b: to make visible or manifest
> 2b: to create or produce especially by deliberate effort over time 
> 4a: to cause to evolve or unfold gradually
>
> #### intransitive verb
>
> 3: to come into being gradually

Answer (score 5):

**accrete**

> grow by accumulation or coalescence.
>
> - form (a composite whole or a collection of things) by gradual accumulation: "the collection of art he had accreted was to be sold"

This is not the best fit for the scenario given in the OP, but the verb struck me upon reading the OP title.

Example usage:

> After many sessions, the features of his psychosis accreted into something recognizable: sociopathy.

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer. Still, it's a good practice, when answering a question of this sort, to come up with a couple of sample sentences.

Comment: @Ricky Example added.

Comment: Splendid! I wish I could give you a second upvote, but that's not allowed, alas.

Answer (score 4):

> OP: It would be great if the word could be used for the process of getting to know someone better (their character would be taking on shape slowly the more you get to know them).

[Blossom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blossom)
*a peak period or stage of development*

"Blossom" evokes flowers and gentle development during a special time of growth.
Flowers and friendship are often use together, such as:

> Still — in a way — nobody sees a flower — really — it is so small — we haven't time — and to see takes time, like to have a friend takes time.
>   [Georgia O'Keeffe](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Georgia_O%27Keeffe)

(This quote, when given to a friend, has its gotcha factor - rambling about flowers and then - there it is - an endearment.)

Comment: Yes, I think this is a good word for a relationship. It suggests a young tentative communication unfolding into a beautiful sharing of mutual understanding. 

e.g. ."The acquaintanceship thus formed, blossomed into friendship, and from that time, until Lord Tennyson's death, this friendship never lessened...  " 

 - from Life of Sir Henry Parkes, G.C.M.G.: Australian Statesman
By Charles E. Lyne

Answer (score 3):

**Grow** or **Evolve**

*Our friendship (grew, evolved) from common interests.*

Evolve  [[Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evolve),  [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/evolve?s=t)]

> - verb (used with object), evolved, evolving.
>
>   1. to develop gradually
> - verb (used without object), evolved, evolving.
>
>   3. to come forth gradually into being; develop; undergo evolution

Grow [[Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grow), [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/grow?s=t)]

> - 6.
>     to come to be by degrees; become:

Comment: I like evolve,  grow not as much. Why do so many people give multiple answers ?

Comment: @Tom22 Should I separate the two, and post two answers? They seem similar enough to be together, and StackExchange is rather insistent upon asking *"Are you sure you want to add another answer? You could refine & improve your existing answer instead."*

Answer (score 3):

It's *very* basic but the verb usage of "*form*"

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for may be to ***refine*** which means:

"to make more fine, subtle, or precise,
or
to improve or perfect by pruning or polishing".

For example:
My opinion of you is getting **refined** every day as I am getting to know you more

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the word [***transition***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transition)

*"the process or a period of changing from one state or condition to another"*

Answer (score 1):

**Intensify, intensifies** [dictionary.com][1] might work for both a silhouette and a relationship

> to make more acute; strengthen or sharpen.

Consider also **emanates** and **emanation**--good for a ghost, perhaps not so good for a person.

> to flow out, issue, or proceed, as from a source or origin; come
>   forth; originate.

Answer (score 1):

Realize it's not so befitting considering the requirement you raised in the second paragraph but my first instinct when I saw the question was to answer with the word **primordial**, provoked by my thoughts of the slow, sprawling transformation of early Earth.

A much more interesting fit though to my mind due to its commonality in our language and simultaneously a more expansive perspective of its definition:

**Stew**.  Seems to me all of the below definitions of its use as a verb from Dictionary.com could easily be described as  states of change resulting in a new form, tangible or intangible.

```
to undergo cooking by simmering or slow boiling.

Informal. to fret, worry, or fuss:
He stewed about his chaotic state of affairs all day.

to feel uncomfortable due to a hot, humid, stuffy atmosphere, as in a closed room; swelter.
```

Stumbled through this site in the past but your question prompted me to sign up with that, thought it was an interesting non-standard use of the word.

Answer (score 0):

**Warp**.  Although it means to twist out of shape, when used to describe a character of a person, it could mean **transform** into a new less appealing shape.  Maybe **transform** can be used in a more neutral (ie, less negative) way.

Comment: *Transform* and *warp* both describe changing from an original, known version. That's not really what was being asked here.

Comment: @lly, when it comes to a literary character, you often witness a *transformation* from an unknown to a fully-formed entity through a process of "getting to know them better".

Answer (score 0):

**Mature**

*"v.intr.
 1. To evolve toward or reach full development"*  - http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mature

Example: *"...the friendship matured over the years..."* -
 from **Friends and Sisters**: Letters Between Lucy Stone and Antoinette Brown, 1846-93 
by Lucy Stone, Antoinette Louisa Brown Blackwell, University of Illinois Press, 1987

Answer (score -1):

An adjective for something that 'takes shape slowly' could be **viscous**.

Although this mainly refers to liquids that can't pour easily, for example honey, mud and crude oil all are a all viscous.

If you pour a viscous liquid on a flat table, it will indeed take shape slowly. You could use this metaphorically, I suppose like any other adjective in the English language however someone would need to have a very good grasp of the English language to understand.

With rarely-used words like these it may be best to simply take **two simple words and combine them**. I.e. just say **slow-forming** and everyone will understand perfectly.

viscous

adjective

Having a thick, sticky consistency between solid and liquid; having a high viscosity.

"viscous lava"

Comment: It's a different sense of *take shape*. OP meant *within one's mind* or *vision*, not *physically*.

Answer (score -1):

in·cho·ate
inˈkōət,ˈinkəˌwāt/
adjective
just begun and so not fully formed or developed; rudimentary.
"a still inchoate democracy"

Comment: Please provide a citation for your quote, and please take the site [tour]

Comment: Thanks for posting, but *inchoate* describes the person when he can't really make them out. The question was asking for the word that means *becoming less inchoate*.

Answer (score -1):

simple word, common usage - sharpen (or a synonym of), could be applied to relationships I guess - our friendship sharpened as we got to know each other...

Comment: While the meaning of sharpen may be obvious to all, it is appreciated if you included a definition that relates to this discussion and mention a source.

Comment: There are ways this word could work (digitally refining a somewhat blurry computer image, e.g.), but I wouldn't take a "sharpened" friendship as a good thing...

Comment: lly, agreed, not a great adjective in that context. Vicky, apologies, I will inculde definitions in future posts. First visit :)